# How to omit fields when using camel-xmljson JAR to convert XML string to JSON string

Tags: json, apache-camel

```
 XmlJsonDataFormat xmlJsonFormat = new XmlJsonDataFormat();
 xmlJsonFormat.setEncoding("UTF-8");
 xmlJsonFormat.setForceTopLevelObject(true);
 xmlJsonFormat.setTrimSpaces(true);
 xmlJsonFormat.setSkipNamespaces(true);
 xmlJsonFormat.setRemoveNamespacePrefixes(true);
```

Pool a XML file from source directory and transform it to JSON format before sending it to destination directory

```
 from("file:/inn?noop=true").marshal(xmlJsonFormat)
                .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, simple("${file:onlyname.noext}.json"))
                .to("file:/out").end();
```

It works great when i want a JSON string right from a XML without using a POJO.

But now consider a XML where I would like to omit an element. 
Should I use another lib but camel-xmljson? 
Is this way the right  way of accomplish it:

1. JAXB lib to get a POJO from XML
2. Jackson lib to get a JSON from POJO and with excluding POJO fields from marshalling

Comment: I suppose you could use XSTL to transform your XML into something that would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I understand, even I would try to avoid any POJO's in camel routes.

Having said that, I wont just straight way let the XML out. I would put a XSLT after the xmljson component, so that I can trim the xml for desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks gnanagurus! This is quite simple using XSLT. Moreover the xslt: component is included in the last version of the core of Camel.
I defined an xlst file 'transform.xsl' taht includes the field that is to be omited. And then defined the Camel route like that:

```
from("file:/inn?noop=true")
            .to("xslt:file:src/transform.xsl")
            .marshal(xmlJsonFormat)
            .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, simple("${file:onlyname.noext}.json"))
            .to("file:/out").end();
```